# ¿Por qué mi variable SASS de CSS escrita en SCSS no funciona?

Tags: html, css

Tengo el siguiente código que estoy desarrollando en Dreamweaver, he hecho la instalación de SASS en la terminal de mi Mac, no de Ruby ya que viene de serie en los Mac y aún así la variable $green no funciona de ninguna manera...Gracias.

```css
$green:rgba(254,185,54,1.00);
body{margin:none; overflow:hidden;; background: rgba(239,234,150,0.80); }
.square0{position:absolute; left:0%; width:50px;height:50px; bottom:0px;z-index:2000; border:1px solid black; background-color: $green;}
```

```html
<div class="square0"></div>
```

Comment: El código Sass es correcto y compila de la manera que se espera. En todo caso, lo que está mal es tu instalación del Sass o la forma en la que lo estás llamando. Asegúrate que la instalación es correcta y edita tu pregunta agregando información de como ejecutas la compilación

Comment: Verifica la estructura de tu projecto http://thesassway.com/beginner/how-to-structure-a-sass-project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Después de `$green` coloca `=` y no `:`

```css
$green = rgba(254, 185, 54, 1);
body {
margin: none;
overflow: hidden;
background: rgba(239, 234, 150, .8);
}
.square0 {
position: absolute;
left: 0%;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
bottom: 0px;
z-index: 2000;
border: 1px solid black;
background-color: $green;
}
```

```html
<div class="square0"></div>
```

Comment: ¿cómo debería ser?

Comment: Usar = en vez de :

Comment: Gracias no había notado el matiz. Aún así no funciona, creo que puede ser por este mensaje que aparece en el visualizador de fallos de Koala: Individual stylesheets must be in sass directory pero no sé a qué se refiere

Comment: De nada, también observa que en el overflow pusiste doble punto y coma.

Comment: Perdona, puede ser el error lo del sass directory?

Comment: Espero eso sulucione tu problema.

Comment: No lo hace, creo que el problema es lo de sass directory y no tengo ni ieda de como solucionar eso.

Comment: Por el error que mencionaste hace un rato, es problemante por que el archivos sass no lo tienes en el directorio correcto osea en la carpeta correcta.

Comment: De verdad, no encuentro cómo solucionarlo, cómo hago para que esté en la carpeta correcta? o cómo hago que una carpeta sea correcta? he hecho lo del terminal y no hay manera.

Comment: No renderiza lo que quiero, ese es el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Tu codigo está bien, puedes pegarlo aquí para comprobar que compila correctamente: http://www.sassmeister.com/

En los comentarios dices que te da un error el Koala. Mira a ver si estás usando compass para compilar, si es así o lo quitas o tienes que estar en el directorio que tiene el archivo `config.rb`